# Digiwack File Utilities example code?

Tags: android

My app allows users to select a file on their **Android device**. How can my app use *Digiwack File Utilities* on **Android**?

Answer (score 0):

In activity code, call it this way:

```
Intent in = new Intent("com.digiwack.util.FileSelect");
in.putExtra("currFolder",Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
in.putExtra("operation",0); //indicates "select" operation
//in.putExtra("operation", 1); //indicates "save" operation   
//in.putExtra("operation", 2); //indicates "load" operation
startActivityForResult(in, 1); //or any result-code will do
```

In activity's `onActivityResult()` method, add this part:

```
if (resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==yourRequestCode) {
    String filename = data.getExtras().getString("selectedFile");
    if (filename!=null) {
       //user selected a file
       File yourFile = new File(filename);
       //use yourFile as your app see's fit from here on out
    }
}
```